# Is anyone having any problems with the new Xcode 10.3 update?

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode10.3

I recently updated mine, and I am having all types of problems. 1. I am getting blue lines around all of my UI layouts (buttons, labels, stacks, etc). All I see are blue lines, no content. The warning I get is: "An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited." Also, whenever I try to run my app, it says that "A build only device cannot be used to run this target."

Is my project gone or messed up. How can I fix this?

I have tried force quitting Xcode multiple times, and reporting the bug, but no such luck.

Answer (score 8):

I have faced the same issue, and after a deep research, I decided to restart my computer. This solved the problem.

Comment: solved for me! thought this was another classic Xcode update where everything goes to @#$%!!